# How to check if all records for a given key are in the same partition already?

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to avoid repartitioning data set by key as much as possible and know if all records for a given key are in the same partition already.

Is there a built-in function in Spark that would give me the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in but if you assume specific partitioner it is easy enough to implement your own function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def checkDistribution[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](
   rdd: RDD[(K, V)], partitioner: Partitioner) = 
  // If partitioner is set we compare partitioners 
  rdd.partitioner.map(_ == partitioner).getOrElse {
    // Otherwise check if correct number of partitions 
    rdd.partitions.size ==  partitioner.numPartitions &&
    //  And check if distribution matches partitioner
    rdd.keys.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => 
      Iterator(iter.forall(x => partitioner.getPartition(x) == i))
    ).fold(true)(_ && _)
  }
```

A few tests:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val rdd = sc.range(0, 20, 5).map((_, None))
```

- Not partitioned, invalid distribution:

  ```scala
  checkDistribution(rdd, new HashPartitioner(10))
  ```

  ```
  Boolean = false
  ```
- Partitioned, invalid partitioner:

  ```scala
  checkDistribution(
    rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(5)),
    new HashPartitioner(10)
  )
  ```

  ```
  Boolean = false
  ```
- Partitioned, valid partitioner:

  ```scala
  checkDistribution(
    rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10)),
    new HashPartitioner(10)
  )
  ```

  ```
  Boolean = true
  ```
- Not partitioned, valid distribution:

  ```scala
  checkDistribution(
    rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10)).map(identity),
    new HashPartitioner(10)
  )
  ```

  ```
  Boolean = true
  ```

Without assuming particular partitioner the only option that comes to mind requires shuffle, so it it unlikely to be an improvement.

```scala
def checkDistribution[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)]) =
   rdd.keys.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => iter.map((_, i)))
     .combineByKey(
       x => Seq(x), 
       (x: Seq[Int], y: Int) => x, 
       (x: Seq[Int], y: Seq[Int]) => x ++ y)  // Should be more or less OK
     .values
     .mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(iter.forall(_.size == 1)))
     .fold(true)(_ && _)
```

One possible improvement is that you can use the same logic to automatically define `Partitioner` for the data. If you `collectAsMap` before `values` and check that all `Seqs` are of size 1 you have a valid partitioner which guarantees no network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what you requested but you can check this by using spark_partition_id. Basically do:

```
withColumn("pid", spark_partition_id())
```

and then do:

```
df.groupby(what you want to check).agg(max($"pid").as("pidmax"),min($"pid").as("pidmin")).filter($"pidmax"===$"pidmin").count()
```

The count would give you how many elements are not partitioned.
Note that this is relatively low cost being a simple aggregation.

I don't believe there is a generic way because if we read from a generic source (e.g. file), we don't necessarily know how the source was originally partitioned.

It would be nice if there was something like "get current partitioner" which would get explicit partitioners (e.g. if we had an explicit repartition command or reading something from parquet which was written using PartitionBy) as an approximation though.